# How to extend validation of a subitem of my viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf

My model class `Animal` implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo` to add validation. My view is bound to a viewmodel with a property `SelectedAnimal` of type `Animal` like that:

**View**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedAnimal.Epc, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                   ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public Animal SelectedAnimal
{
    get
    {
        return _animal;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(() => Animal, ref _animal, value);
    }
}
```

**Error visualization** works fine:

[image]

### **Question**

I want to add additional validation, of the field EPC that is done *in my viewmodel* not in the `Animal` class. So I want to add another validation rule (e.g. check if EPC is unique), that is visualized with the EPC TextBox.

How can I achieve this? Validation errors of that viewmodel rule should also be shown on the EPC TextBox.

I tried manipulating the list of validation errors of class Animal without success.

---

Additional info

[validation based on class ValidatableModel](https://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/wpf-4-5-validation-asynchrone/)

Comment: the 1st thing that comes to mind is: wrap `SelectedAnimal.Epc` into another property in viewModel, add validation for it and bind TextBox to that property

Comment: @ASh This would replace the original validation of `Animal`, I want to extend it. Wouldn't it?

Comment: I've used FluentValidation library a few times. Google it or here's an article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1069135/Dynamic-Validation-with-FluentValidation-in-WPF-MV

Comment: @nabulke, not necessary.call base validation, return base validation messages + new validation messages

Comment: @ASh: How can I do that?

Comment: @nabulke, please show code for validation which you have currently. it maybe i'm talking about different pattern. also not sure if ErrorTemplate is designed to show multiple messages

Comment: @ASh I added a link in my question to the base class I use for validation that implements INotifyDataErrorInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to solve your problem:

- Wrap the property whose validation you want to extend in your viewmodel

  ```
  public string Epc
  {
      get
      {
         return _epc;
      }
      set
      {
         Animal.Epc = value;
         Set(() => Epc, ref _epc, value, false);
      }
  }
  ```
- Add two custom validation rules to that property

  ```
  [CustomValidation(typeof(ViewModel), "AnimalEpcValidate")]
  [CustomValidation(typeof(ViewModel), "ExtendedEpcValidate")]
  ```
- Add your extended validation code, that is not done by Animal itself, to `ExtendedEpcValidate`
- Call the `Animal.Epc` validation and add the results to the `Epc` validation results in your viewmodel

  ```
  public static ValidationResult AnimalEpcValidate(object obj, ValidationContext context)
  {
      var aevm = context.ObjectInstance as ViewModel;

      // get errors from Animal validation
      var animalErrors = aevm.Animal.GetErrors("Epc")?.Cast<string>();

      // add errors from Animal validation to your Epc validation results
      var error = animalErrors?.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, animalError) => current + animalError);

      // return aggregated errors of Epc property
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)
                 ? ValidationResult.Success
                 : new ValidationResult(error, new List<string> { "Epc" });
  }
  ```